# undefeatable TFS error: TF400030: The local data store is currently in use by another operation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

No matter what I do, when I touch TFS in any way, it gives me the error:

`TF400030: The local data store is currently in use by another operation. Please wait and then try your operation again. If this error persists, restart the application.`

Well not everything, I can see a list of workspaces (all 1 of them). But trying to view the workspace in the source control explorer will only show "Working..." Pending changes can only show me there are 654 included changes (a migration, don't judge), but none of the actual changed files and strangely none of the excluded changes.

I tried to nuke this workspace and rebuild it from scratch. But even using `tf.exe workspace /delete ...`, right after a fresh reboot, will give me the above error.

I tried deleting all VS / TFS related folders from `AppData\Local\Microsoft` and running `devenv.exe /resetuserdata` afterwards as explained by [Willy-P. Schaub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).

Then running `tf.exe workspaces` results in `No workspace matching * found on this computer.` ... until starting VS again, after which my workspace is visible again

As explained by [Philip Kelly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2013/05/31/tf400030-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation/) the TF400030 error might be because of a scanner running. But I don't know how to locate / kill such a scanner and no process on my PC is doing any significant IO.

I fear spending the time to reinstall VS would result in this exact same situation and reinstalling my PC seems a bit excessive.

Is there a way to make the TFS client forget about my local workspace? Or even better hunt down and kill whatever other process causes the TF400030?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sigh* sometimes the answer is so easy: I just rename the mapped folder on disk and TFS started responding again.